# how to broadcast to only caller with Signalr IhubContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a Signalr Hub to notify user when have a new data inserted to Database

**hub**

```
public class NotifyHub : Hub
{
    public void NotifyAllClients(string source, string msg)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotifyHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayNotification(source, msg);

    }
}
```

**Client**

```
   $(function () {
        var notify = $.connection.notifyHub;

        notify.client.displayNotification = function (source,msg) {
            new PNotify({
                title: source,
                text: msg,
                type: 'success',
                styling: 'bootstrap3'
            });
        };
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
```

**client default.aspx codebehind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    SendNotifications();
}


public void SendNotifications()
{
    string message = string.Empty;
    string source = string.Empty;
    string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr)) {
        string query = "SELECT [Source], [MSG] FROM [dbo].[LOG_EVENT] ORDER BY LOG_DATE DESC, LOG_TIME DESC";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) {
            command.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependency.OnChange += dependency_OnChange;

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows) {
                reader.Read();
                source = reader(0).ToString();
                message = reader(1).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    NotifyHub nHub = new NotifyHub();

    nHub.NotifyAllClients(source, message);
}
```

but this notify to **all** client when user connected to hub It caused multiple notify pop up to all user that use webpage.

I know that I can use `caller` property to notify to just caller, but this property not working with `IHubContext` I can't find any solution to solve this

Comment: Could you show how you call `NotifyAllClients` from your client?

Comment: @Mark I updated a code

Comment: ah, because you are not calling `NotifyAllClients` from your clients, instead from your code behind. thats why it doesnt recognized `caller`. Is there any particular reason that you have to use Code Behind? if not, then you can move your code to your HUB class, thus you would be able to use `Caller` after that

Comment: Mark is along the right lines - it's really not easy to link Http callbacks (call behind code or MVC Controller code) with a specific hub connection. Better to just use the `OnConnected` method in the hub and `Caller`

Comment: thank you both of you :) I'll try your ways